# jump to <++> keeping fold

Tags: vim, vimrc, code-folding

to jump in vim, I use

```
 nnoremap <c-j> /<++><cr>c/+>/e<cr>
```

but, when the `<++>` are in a close fold, the `<c-j>` delete all fold, for this I change to

```
 nnoremap <c-j> /<++><cr>zOc/+>/e<cr>
```

but, when the `<++>` are not are in a fold I get

```
 E490: No fold found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `zv` instead of `zO`. That will work without an error message whether in a fold or not.